# How to hide time of execution in Jupyter cells in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am following a course on Python and  Math. As editor I use Jupyter notebooks in VS Code.
I am not able to eliminate (or hide) the time of execution shown in each cell. I searched in Settings, but did not find the relative option.
Could you help, please?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

This now exists in VS Code's 'clickable' settings screen (as opposed to editing the settings.json file.

Search settings for the below, and select 'hidden' from the dropdown.

```
notebook.showCellStatusBar
```

Comment: Hello. I did see the other answer, and obviously both achieve the same thing, but while it describes editing the settings.json, mine does not. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this parameter in the ***settings.json***:

```
"notebook.showCellStatusBar": "hidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question.
I only found this [enhancement issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1454).
It does seem like they did not think of a option to disable it.

For now just switch back to normal Jupyter notebooks.